# How to Make Custom Audio Wave In flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How To Make Custom Audio Wave And effect In Flutter
pls tell me

I Used Audio Wave Dependency But Not Get What I want

Comment: What do you mean by custom audio wave? Do you mean you want to show the waveform of the file or that you want to synthesize a sound?

Comment: Please add some code or what you want because we do not know what you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.